# Detect key press in process (without polling) when other threads might be blocked?

Tags: winapi, keypress

How do I immediately detect that the user has pressed a key within my process without needing any cooperation from the GUI thread's message loop? (I know `GetAsyncKeyState` can do this with polling, but I want a notification-based mechanism.)

For example, say I want to detect if the user presses <kbd>F8</kbd> and spawn a process in that case, even when the GUI thread might be blocked on arbitrary things. What's the best way to do this, ideally without slowing down the rest of the program or increasing CPU usage (as polling would)?

Comment: there is no such thing as *pressed a key within my process* . key only can be pressed within window (which has keyboard focus). as result window procedure of wthis window got this event. and GUI thread must no be blocked , but permanent handle events

Comment: @RbMm: Then how does Visual Studio detect F12 even when the debugee is completely blocked?

Comment: if you press F12 in context of **window** of app, which have debugger attached, system call `DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin` (probably from csrss.exe) fot this process. as result thread  with ep `DbgUiRemoteBreakin` created in app and `int 3` instruction executed. debugger got exception.

Comment: yes, `winsrv!SrvActivateDebugger` inside csrss.exe (which executed in same terminal session as app, in which window F12 pressed) call `DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin`

Comment: if be more exactly `xxxDoHotKeyStuff` (from win32kfull.sys) call `xxxActivateDebugger` which call (via `LpcRequestPort`) `SrvActivateDebugger` in csrss.exe . it called  `DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin` - as result `DbgUiRemoteBreakin` and `int 3` called in target app. and via exception - attached debugger got event

Comment: `RawInputThread` call `SetDebugHotKeys` which register hot key for `VK_F12`. so all begin in this thread.

Comment: @RbMm: Interesting, thanks.